# Accessing a variable in a tbl in a list in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to figure out how to write a function that will access a variable in a tbl that is stored in a list. I'm using the srvyr package because I also need to incorporate survey design elements.

```
#Example

library(tidyverse)
library(srvyr)

num <- c(1:50)
var <- rnorm(50)

data <- data.frame(num, var) %>%
  mutate(name = ifelse(num > 25, "Yes", "No"))

#This works fine as long as it's a dataframe

foo <- function(x)  {
  data %>%
    group_by(data[,x]) %>%
    summarise(n = n())
}

foo("name")

#With a slight edit this works for a tbl.

data_tbl <- as.tbl(data)

foo2 <- function(x)  {
  data_tbl %>%
    group_by(data_tbl[[x]]) %>%
    summarise(n = n())
}

foo2("name")

#Now the question is how to make this work for a tbl in a list.

sur <- data %>%
  as_survey_design(ids = 1)

#This seems to access what I want.

sur$variables[["name"]]

#But it doesn't work inside the function. 

foo3 <- function(x)  {
  sur %>%
    group_by(sur$variables[[x]]) %>%
    summarise(proportion = survey_mean())
}

foo3("name")

#Any thoughts?
```

Any ideas? Unless working with the srvyr packages complicates this somehow, I expect there's a very simple solution.

Thanks!

Comment: role of survey_mean? example??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try.

```
foo3 <- function(x)  {
  sur %>%
    group_by_at(x) %>% 
    summarise(proportion = survey_mean())
}

foo3("name")
```

**output**

```
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  name  proportion proportion_se
  <chr>      <dbl>         <dbl>
1 No           0.5        0.0714
2 Yes          0.5        0.0714
```

Comment: Neel, thanks so much for the input. I think this is probably half the answer. "survey_mean" is a function within the srvyr package that accounts for the design elements stored in other lists, etc. in sur. The call sur[["variables"]] results in the error "Survey context not set" because (presumably) the function doesn't have access to those other design elements stored in sur. Is there a way to only call sur[["variables"]] within group_by? Or group_by_at?

Comment: @num_39 Edited my answer. see the output. I was really close. Just replace `group_by` with `group_by_at` .

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks so much, @Neel!